# FluentValidation in ASP.NET complex properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have the following situation. I have a class, for example

```
public class Person 
{
   public SchoolYear FirstYear {get; set;}
   public SchoolYear SecondYear {get; set;}
}

public class SchoolYear
{
   public string YearStartDate {get; set;}
   public string YearEndDate {get; set;}
}
```

I want to make sure that the start of the second school year is ONE DAY AFTER the end of the first school year and I want to do it with the FluentValidation library. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check it.

```
   public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
    {
        public PersonValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.SecondYear).Must((p, s)=> {
                var firstYear = p.FirstYear;
                var secondYear = p.SecondYear;
                return Convert.ToDateTime(secondYear.YearStartDate) == Convert.ToDateTime(firstYear.YearEndDate).AddDays(1);
            })
              .WithMessage("second school year should be ONE DAY AFTER firstYear YearEndDate ");
        }
    }
```

For more details about custom validator [follow](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html) it.